# how to handle update requests to different tables using hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I have a json object that inturn contains objects from different tables, so when I get an update request it can contain one or more object and these objects can be columns of the same or different tables. Is there a way to handle this or do we need have different db calls for each table. Please help me out with the best approach. I get the json object through web-services(REST).

Answer (score 0):

Typically you would need to convert/map the json data to the entity graph (data model) of your application. Since you need to update, the data would be containing the primary key identifier too. Such an object instance is known as "detached" in Hibernate parlance. You can then use saveorupdate / merge API calls to update the whole entity graph which will result into updates in relevant tables and columns. Also you would need cascade feature to call the API method once on the parent object so that it is automatically propagated to the complete graph or you can manually call the operation on each object ( the former option is more convenient though).

Comment: Is there a sample code I can go through to understand this better, I have not worked much in hibernate.

Comment: I would then strongly suggest you to first just go through any of the Hibernate tutorials (there are plenty) to understand how hibernate inserts / updates a network of objects. Once you grasp that, you would simply need to map your json object to entity object graph and you're done ! Eventually your json would translate to a relations of objects and you need to update these to database tables.